# React Navigation passing props to class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

The react navigation documentation is very clear on how to pass props to functional components, but what about class-based components?

This is a screen that scans a QR code and passes the data to a `class-based component`

```
export const ScreenQRCodeScanner = ({ navigation }) => {
...
  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
    var clientID = {
      ClientID: data,
    };
    navigation.navigate("QRCodeResult", clientID);
  };
...
};
```

`QRCodeResult` is this function:

```
export class QRCodeResult extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      clientInfo: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    // API call with a dynamic body based on data passed from the previous screen (clientID)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Test QR Code Result Page {this.state.clientInfo.FullName}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.loading}</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using `react navigation v5` and I want to use the data passed on `componentDidMount()` function where I make an API call

Answer (score 0):

You can access the navigation prop like below

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("QRCodeResult", {clientID});
```

And if the receiving component is also a class component you can retrieve it like below.

```
this.props.route.params.clientID
```